# JavaScript - Write Variable to a .txt file and then load it

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a Discord Bot that has a variable 0-9999. 
I need to be able to store that variable (let's say 9) into a .txt file,
and then whenever the Bot starts, it reads the file and sets the variable as
the first line of the text document.

So example:
Variable is 9. 9 is written to a text document on the first line. 
Whenever I start the bot, Variable is set to the first line of text
document (9)

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure how Discord bots work, but I know Discord is made with Electron and Node.js, so you could probably use the file system package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs)
Install it with:

```
npm install fs --save -g
```

You can read from the file like this:

```
// File system stuff.
var fs = require("fs");

// Get the text file and load it into a variable.
var file = fs.readFileSync("path/to/my/text/file.txt", "utf8");
```

And you can write to the file like this:

```
// Write the file
fs.writeFile("path/to/my/text/file.txt", myVariable, function (err) {

    // Checks if there is an error
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

why not instead use cookies? If you're writing something for the browser you shouldn't store data in text files on the client's computer. If you are using nodejs for server code you could write text files but it would be better to use some sort of database.

Comment: This is a Discord Bot, not a browser application, so cookies are useless. NodeJS is being used for the bot, so how could I go about setting up a database? I have a MySQL database I can use, just have no clue where to start.